# String comparison C++

Tags: c++

I want to check `szDir` in `szSelectedDir`. I want the function to consider the below inputs are different. My sample function is not handling the scenario, please let me know the good solutions.

```
string szSelectedDir ="C:\\Windows1\Test";
string szDir="C:\\Windows";

void IsWindowsDirectory(const string szSpecialPath, const string szSelectedPath)
{

    if(szSelectedPath.compare(szSpecialPath) == 0)
    {
        printf("Both paths are same ");

    }
    else if(szSelectedPath.find(szSpecialPath) != string::npos)
    {
        printf("Both paths are same ");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Both paths are different ");

    }

}
```

Comment: `if (szSelectedPath == szSpecialPath)` yay for operators!

Comment: I assume the `string` class you're using is actually `std::string` and you have a `using std::string;` somewhere at the top of your code file?

Comment: The problem is underspecified. What kinds of paths would you consider identical? For the record, Windows filesystem is case-insensitive.

Comment: Also, this is so completely wrong on a level beyond the code. There is absolutely **no** guarantee that the Windows directory will be named `Windows`, much less that it will reside on the `C:` drive. Hard-coding paths is a huge no-no, and this detection method is doomed to fail. Call the [`GetWindowsDirectory` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724454.aspx) and skip the comparison altogether.

Comment: Inputs:
string szSelectedDir ="C:\\Windows\Test";
string szDir="C:\\Windows

 Expected Results: szSelectedDir  contains szDir


Inputs:
string szSelectedDir ="C:\\WindowsTest\Test";
string szDir="C:\\Windows

 Expected Results: szSelectedDir  contains szDir, but path is different, so I want to ignore this.

Comment: The windows path I will find by using windows API.

Comment: Checking whether one string contains another is obviously the wrong approach, as your counter-example shows.

Answer (score 0):

To check `szDir` in `szSelectedDir`.

```
if (szSelectedDir.find(szDir) != string::npos)
{
    // You found szDir in szSelectedDir
}
```

As someone already said, comparing strings in C++ is pretty straightforward...

```
if (szSelectedPath == szSpecialPath)
```

I suggest you to pass strings by reference (strings not null, amongst other things).

Comment: Note passing objects by `const&` is generally to avoid the cost of a copy and to prevent changing the original object via the reference. While `const` by value as OP currently is doing is rather odd only pointers can be null.